# Rounding frame_time and smooth transitions for gganimate

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I have the following data frame:

```
# Seed RNG
set.seed(33550336)

# Create data frame
df <- data.frame(x = runif(100), 
                 y = runif(100), 
                 t = runif(100, min = 0, max = 10))
```

I'd like to plot points (i.e., at `x` and `y` coordinates) appearing and disappearing as a function of `t`. `gganimate` is awesome, so I used that.

```
# Load libraries
library(gganimate)
library(ggplot2)

# Create animation
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y))
g <- g + geom_point(colour = "#FF3300", shape = 19, size = 5, alpha = 0.25)
g <- g + labs(title = 'Time: {frame_time}')
g <- g + transition_time(t)
g <- g + enter_fade() + exit_fade()
animate(g, fps = 1)
```

This code produced the following:

[image]

There are a couple of things that I don't like about this.

1. The transitions are very abrupt. My hope using `enter_fade` and `exit_fade` was that the points would fade into view, then back out. Clearly this isn't the case, but how *would* I achieve this result?
2. I would like to round `{frame_time}`, so that while the points fade in and out at fractions of `t`, the actual time `t` that would be shown would be an integer. If `frame_time` was a regular variable, this would be simple enough using something like `bquote` and `round`, but this doesn't seem to be the case. How can I round `frame_time` in my title?

Comment: For part 2, you can round the time with `Time: {round(frame_time,2)}`.

Comment: @MrFlick Works great. Can you point me towards some documentation or a SO answer that explains what's happening with regards to the curly braces and `frame_time` in the title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a relatively manual approach that relies on doing more of the prep beforehand and feeding that into `gganimate`. I'd like to see if there's a simpler way to do this inside `gganimate` more automatically.

First I make a copy of the data frame for each frame I want to show. Then I calculate the difference between the time I'm presently viewing (`time`) and the `t` when I want to show each data point. I use `cos` to handle the easing in and out, so that each dot's appearance at given time is described with `display`. In the ggplot call, I then map alpha and size to `display`, and use `transition_time(time)` to move through the frames.

```
# Create prep table
fade_time = 1
frame_count = 100
frames_per_time = 10
df2 <- map_df(seq_len(frame_count), ~df, .id = "time") %>%
  mutate(time = as.numeric(time)/frames_per_time,
         delta_norm = (t - time) / fade_time,
         display = if_else(abs(delta_norm) > 1, 0, cos(pi / 2 * delta_norm)))


# Create animation
g <- ggplot(df2, aes(x = x, y = y, alpha = display, size = display))
g <- g + geom_point(colour = "#FF3300", shape = 19)
g <- g + scale_alpha(range = c(0, 1)) + scale_size_area(max_size = 5)
g <- g + labs(title = "{round(frame_time, 1)}") 
g <- g + transition_time(time)
animate(g)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. I'd hoped there was a simple way of doing this implemented already in `gganimate`, but this solves the problem.

Comment: The `{code in here}` notation is actually quite clever. It allows you to compute anything you would normally do in R. i.e. - `labs(title = Time: "{round(frame_time, 1)}, Year = {2000 + round(frame_time, 1)}") `.